# Contact form 7 - Manipulate response messages

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a contact form 7 form where a user can input his/her e-mail address and a coupon code. If the e-mail-address or code cannot be found in the database, distinct error messages should be displayed to the user after the submit.

I use the wpcf7_before_send_mail hook to find out if the e-mail address / coupon code are valid:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function');
function your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function($contact_form)
{
    //get user e-mail and coupon nr from database
    $entry = select("SELECT e-mail, coupon_nr FROM {$wpdb->prefix} woocommerce_coupons WHERE coupon_nr = '{$couponNr}'");

    if (is_null($entry[0]->e-mail) 
    {
        $skipMail = true;
        $status = "USER_NOT_FOUND";
    } 
    else if(is_null($entry[0]->coupon_nr) 
    {
        $skipMail = true;
        $status = "COUPON_INVALID";
    } 
    else 
    {
        $status = "OK";
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to display an appropriate error message to the user depending on the status. E.g. if status is "USER_NOT_FOUND", a different message should be displayed as if the status was "COUPON_INVALID".

Any help is very appreciated.